# Virtual reality interface

Tags: feature-request

Now that VR is becoming a big thing again, with the release of Oculus Rift and Playstation VR doing quite well, the lack of VR support on Stack Exchange is a significant drawback.

Can we have a virtual holographic interface to float around my kitchen, please?

Comment: When not an April fool, this is the most useless feature request ever.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: Arguably more useful than a TV channel.

Comment: Honestly when I first read this I thought you said "a virtual holographic interface for my floating kitten".

Answer (score 4):

Actually, there is already a little known Oculus Rift VR app that will let you visit the Stack Exchange Headquarters and even meet some of the lead developers as they go by their daily activities.

You can download it [here](http://kaitouace.com/vr/). No need to thank me.

Comment: No rickroll, disappointed.

Comment: @Magisch Would have been a little lame and generic IMHO. This one is actually real and unicorn/pony themed, but... you opinion is yours. Anyway, enjoy April Fool while it last :P

Comment: Back to real life, you can actually visit inside SE HQ on google maps [here](https://www.google.com.au/maps/place/Stack+Exchange/@40.7086754,-74.0068985,3a,75y,131h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1scjjFCvgcdXAAAAGusaFh2w!2e0!3e2!6s%2F%2Fgeo1.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DcjjFCvgcdXAAAAGusaFh2w%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dsearch.TACTILE.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D129%26h%3D106%26yaw%3D131.19052%26pitch%3D0!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!1m2!2m1!1sstack+exchange!3m1!1s0x89c25a17fe851d8d:0xf9742bc540e39399!6m1!1e1?hl=en). Note: you *can* move around and see the entire office.

Comment: @angussidney I know, and there are also some nice things hidden around, like the Trogdor/Spike cosplayer, the downvotes archives, some flux capacitors,  Princess Stackicorn running around...